# Как в списке картинок сделать overlay только на самой картинке, а не на элементе li? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Есть список картинок, мне нужно, чтобы при наведении был overlay на картинке, я сделал этот overlay, но он срабатывает на элементе `li`, а не на картинке, как сделать, чтобы он срабатывал только на картинке? На прикреплённом скриншоте, видно, что оверлей занимает больше места, чем сама картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой HTML:

```
<ul class="row portfolio-images-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-around justify-content-lg-around">
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_first.png" alt="First Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_second.png" alt="Second Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_third.png" alt="Third Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fourth.png" alt="Fourth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fifth.png" alt="Fifth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_sixth.png" alt="Sixth Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Мой Sass:

```
.portfolio-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;

  .img-border {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #34495e;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }

  &:hover .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }

  .overlay-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемые дяди и тети, скажите, сделайте одолжение - зачем вы код невоспроизводимый суете, затрудняете проблемы решение.

Comment: у меня всё работает прекрасно, скриншот делал я, как ни странно всё работает. Я просто скинул кусок который отвечает за то, где я испытываю проблему.

Comment: посмотрите как сделать [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

Использовал [Селектор следующего элемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)
Смотрите еще здесь: [https://www.w3schools.com/...](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

```css
.portfolio-list-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.portfolio-list-item .img-border {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.portfolio-list-item .img-border:hover + .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.portfolio-list-item .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #34495e;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.portfolio-list-item .overlay:hover {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.portfolio-list-item .overlay-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="row portfolio-images-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-around justify-content-lg-around">
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x280/00BFFF/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="First Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x280/C2ED00/FFFFFF?text=2" alt="Second Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio-list-item col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-border img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x280/EC544D/FFFFFF?text=3" alt="Third Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
        <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Всего вам доброго!

Comment: Автору вопроса - вот это минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример. А у вас кусок кода, который еще и компилировать нужно.